# how to set alias all@example.com means all the user in my email on postfix

Tags: postfix-mta, dovecot

I use my centos 6.5 server to install a mailserver.And it works well.But there is two question.

1. How can i set all@example.com means all the users.This is mean that when i send email to all@example.com,all the users can received.
2. How can i let dovecot if Dovecot can’t find the users in MySQL, it may still be looking for system users.

here is my postfix main.cf:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
local_recipient_maps = 
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = localhost
mydomain = example.com
myhostname = example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = 
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,          permit_mynetworks,          reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

Comment: Off-topic, try http://serverfault.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

You can use mailing list like as mailman or you use virtual_alias_maps (postfix+mysql)

https://workaround.org/ispmail/lenny/postfix-database-mappings
Dovecot has Pigeonhole Dovecot, it has limitation of forwarding mails to 4 Maximum (hard coded in the code so you have to edit the source code and rebuild the dovecot package)

I suggest  you use the first option of mailing list.

Comment: thanks.this is help.I use virtual_alias_maps already and i find that does not work because i have not set this:     dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
    dovecot_destination_concurrency_limit = 1